# Extract data from the frame using C

Tags: c

I have a function as follows:

```
union u_t
{
  uint16_t u16;
  uint8_t u8[2];
};

uint16_t Frame2Data(uint8_t *data,uint8_t startBit,uint16_t length)
{
  uint16_t mask;
  uint8_t start;
  uint8_t firstByte,offset;
  uint8_t numShift;
  union u_t ut;

  for(i=0;i<16;i++)
  {
    if(length == i)
    mask|=(1<<i);
  }

  firstByte = startBit / 8;
  offset = (firstByte+2) * 8;
  start = startBit + length;
  numShift = offset - start;
  ut.u8[1] = data[firstByte];
  ut.u8[0] = data[firstByte+1];
  return (ut.u16 >> numShift) & mask;
}
```

The start bit is 46 and length is 7 and the data in 8 bytes is `0x00 0x09 0x03 0x84 0x03 0x70 0x02 0xA8` has to be passed. I have to extract the data with start bit 46 and upto a length of 7 bits and find out its value. I have a doubt with numbershift and is my function working correctly? It would be great if someone confirms this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is "length"? Why is it 7 when there are 8 data bits? What do you mean "extract the data with start bit 46"? How can a bit have any other value than 0 or 1? There is no sequence in the data provided which is 46 or 0x2E.

Comment: i meant 8 bytes i.e.,64 bits of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here, is the way in which you set your mask:

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    if(length == i)
    mask|=(1<<i); /* BTW, mask is not initialized */
}
```

is simply equivalent to:

```
mask |= (1 << length);
```

which will set only one bit in you mask. So either you substruct one from `mask` after the `for`, or you set it directly:

```
#define UINT16_WIDTH 16
mask = (1u << (length & (UINT16_WIDTH - 1))) - 1u;
```

Comment: `mask = (1u << ((length & (UINT16_WIDTH - 1)) - 1u);` Is it right?

Comment: @user8540390, thanks for the note, I forgot some parentheses :).